# Genstage and polling are a recommended pattern?

Tags: elixir, gen-server, genstage

I'm developing my first medium/big application in elixir and I'm trying to get familiar with the common patterns in elixir system design and architectures.

At this moment I'm trying to implement an input queue (currently implemented using the erlang :queue), exposed through and API and I want to have consumers from that queue performing some processing and storing the data.

I have created the queue using an Agent and I have implemented a genStage that queries the queue for elements and a genstage consumer for performing all the processing that I need. In summary something like this

Queue Agent -------> GenStage producer ---------> GenStage consumer -----> database

My questions are the following:

1. Is this pattern valid for Elixir?
2. Is a valid pattern the polling that the GenStage producer is performing on the Queue, asking everytime that consumers requests for new elements?
3. Are there any performance implication in this pattern, specially are there any possible blocking implications in the Queue Agent?

Comment: Is there a requirement for FIFO?  Or could you send messages directly to the GenStage producer?

Comment: Putting `GenStage` after `Agent` makes a very little sense, because `Agent`’s mailbox  would be the bottleneck. Use `ets` instead (or any other kind of message broker / key-value storage.)

Comment: I hadn't realised that `GenStage` are based on `GenServer` and I have the `cast` method to update the internal state. 

So now I have refactored everything and I only have one `GenStage` producer and a consumer

Comment: Usually polling can be avoided in Elixir thank to the workers (GenServer/GenStage) inbox. But could you tell us a little more about the context of your application? This could help us to understand the problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some comments and reading documentation I realised that `GenStage` is based on `GenServer` and I have the possibility to manage the internal state from outside the `GenStage`.

After this I refactored the code and now I have the `:queue` as part of the `GenStage` state, so I don't need to polling any queue outside the `GenStage` and I also have the possibility to add elements into the queue using the `handle_cast` method.

Now I have the Queue working as a `GenStage` producer and I have been able to connect my database service as a consumer